# TextView out of the Screen

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm building a chat Application, So I'm displaying bubbles as background of the textView and also an imageView.

To be able to differ messages from users, I hide a imageView (using visibilty.Gone) and change the layout_gravity to right ou left to correctly display the message.

Everything is working great, except when the message from the "Mark Zuckerberg" (and only when it's from him) is too longo, the textview goes out of the screen.

Here is my layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<br.com.guitcastro.meetapp.views.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/leftImageView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:visibility="visible" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/comment"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:layout_margin="10dp"
    android:background="@drawable/bubble_purple"
    android:gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
    android:text="Hello bubbles! This is a very ver"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />

<br.com.guitcastro.meetapp.views.CircularImageView
    android:id="@+id/rightImageView"
    android:layout_width="70dp"
    android:layout_height="70dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

The code to display the "right" layout:

```
   if (left) {
        rightImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        leftImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        this.setImageDrawable(leftImageView, me);

        messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
        wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    } else {
        leftImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rightImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.setImageDrawable(rightImageView, StringUtils.parseName(message.getFrom()));

        messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);
        wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
```

Here is a screenShot, what I have for now (I know the bubbles are wrong, please ignore, this isn't important right now).

[image]

Comment: Are the three layout items you've shown contained in a horizontal linear layout? if so try giving the TextView a width of "0dp" and weight of 1.

Comment: Yes it is, I just updated my question. Already done that, indeed this prevent the text from going out the screen, but this also increase the textViewSize when the message is small (like the first one)

Comment: Use weights instead if so so that the the bubble doesn't get pushed off by scaling

Comment: @zgc7009, could you explain to me how? I don't have experience in Android

Comment: Yea give me a minute, and that is supposed to say "of dp" not "if so" but my phone and I don't get along sometimes

Comment: you can use weight property for that.

Comment: weight property make the textview stretch =/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
// try this way,hope this will help you...

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/wrapper"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <br.com.guitcastro.meetapp.views.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/leftImageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1">
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/comment"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:background="@drawable/bubble_purple"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="Hello bubbles! This is a very ver"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
            android:textColor="@android:color/primary_text_light" />
    </LinearLayout>


    <br.com.guitcastro.meetapp.views.CircularImageView
        android:id="@+id/rightImageView"
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="70dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: weight property make the textview stretch =/

Comment: Amazing!, I'm felling so stupid for didn't think in this before!

Answer (score 3):

```
maybe this can help you

// get dimensions
Display display = getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
        int width = display.getWidth(); // largura

// get dimensions in percent
double percentWidth = width/100;

int percentToSetHeight = percentHeight*80;

if (left) {
        rightImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        leftImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        messageText.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    messageText.setMaxWidth(percentToSetHeight);
        this.setImageDrawable(leftImageView, me);

        messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_green);
        wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.LEFT);
    } else {
        leftImageView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        rightImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        this.setImageDrawable(rightImageView, StringUtils.parseName(message.getFrom()));
    messageText.setMaxWidth(percentToSetHeight);
        messageText.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bubble_yellow);
        wrapper.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);
    }
```